# Order two unramified character of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field. Then $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$ has an order-two unramified character "corresponding to" the nontrivial central element of its dual group $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$. What is this character explicitly, say when $n=2$? I thought I understood the relationship between the real Lie algebra and unramified characters, but I guess I still don't.

For example, when $n=1$, the character I am confused about must be the character of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(F)\simeq \mathrm{SO}_3(F)$ given by composing the determinant with the nontrivial order two unramified character.

Comment: Hey, I can sort of answer this if you'd like. Namely, I think that there is a canonical identification $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)/\mathrm{Spin}_{2n+1}(F)\xrightarrow{\approx}H^1(F,\mu_2)=F^\times/(F^\times)^2$, where 'canonical' means the one associated to the sequence 

$$1\to \mu_2\to \mathrm{Spin}_{2n+1,F}\to \mathrm{SO}_{2n+1,F}\to 1.$$

The unique unramified character is then the composition of this homomorphism with the unique order $2$ unramified character of $F^\times$. Unfortunately, this is 'canonical' but I don't know if you'd call it 'explicit'.

Comment: I have now (I believe) actually answered your question satisfactorily. I am commenting here in case it doesn't ping you with my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I have made a mistake (which is possible, so please check it), I can explain how to 'canonically' construct this order $2$ unramified character. Of course, 'canonical' and 'explicit' are not the same thing, and I still think it would be nice if someone could point out more explicitly what this character is (**EDIT:** see the edit at the bottom of the post). Maybe this will help you (or someone else) find such a description. For simplicitly, let me assume that the residue characteristic of our fields is greater than $2$.

> **Proposition:** *Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group over $F$. Then, there is a
> canonical isomorphism*
>
> $$\left\{\text{continuous }\chi \colon G(F)\to
>  \mathbf{C}^\times\right\} \xrightarrow{\approx} \left\{\nu\colon
>  H^1(F,\pi_1(G))\to \mathbf{C}^\times\right\}.$$

Let me clarify the notation here. Let $G^\mathrm{sc}$ be the universal cover of $G$, and $\pi_1(G)=\ker(G^\mathrm{sc}\to G)$ the fundamental group of $G$, considered as a finite abelian group $F$-scheme. As $\pi_1(G)$ is abelian the Galois cohomology group $H^1(F,\pi_1(G))$ is an abelian group, and thus it makes sense to consider characters of $H^1(F,\pi_1(G))$.

To prove this claim, let us first observe that every continuous character $G^\mathrm{sc}(F)\to\mathbf{C}^\times$ is trivial. The reason for this is that by Chevalley's theorem (see Theorem 10.3.4 of [this](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/249BW16Page/handouts/249B_2016.pdf)) ${G}^\mathrm{sc}(F)$ is generated by subgroups isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2(F)$. This reduces us to proving the claim for $G=\mathrm{SL}_{2,F}$ which can be easily done by hand as $\mathrm{SL}_2(F)^\mathrm{ab}$ is trivial.

From this, we see that for any continuous character $\chi\colon G(F)\to \mathbf{C}^\times$, the composition

$$G^\mathrm{sc}(F)\to G(F)\xrightarrow{\chi}\mathbf{C}^\times$$

is trivial. That said, from the short exact sequence of group $F$-schemes

$$1\to \pi_1(G)\to G^\mathrm{sc}\to G\to 1,$$

(where note that $\pi_1(G)$ is central in $G^\mathrm{sc}$) we get the exact sequence of groups

$$1\to \pi_1(G)(F)\to G^\mathrm{sc}(F)\to G(F)\to H^1(F,\pi_1(G))\to 1.$$

Here I have used Kneser's theorem that $H^1(F,X)$ vanishes for any simply connected group $X$. From this we see that we have a **canonical** isomorphism

$$G(F)/G^\mathrm{sc}(F)\xrightarrow{\approx}H^1(F,\pi_1(G)).$$

As this latter group is abelian, the proposition quickly follows.

Now, for the case $G=\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1,F}$ we can explicitly compute things. Namely, $G^\mathrm{sc}=\mathrm{Spin}_{2n+1,F}$ and $\pi_1(G)=\mu_{2,F}$. Thus, from the above proposition we have a bijection

$$\{\text{continuous }\chi\colon\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)\to\mathbf{C}^\times\}\xrightarrow{\approx}\{\nu\colon F^\times/(F^\times)^2\to\mathbf{C}^\times\},$$

where I have applied Kummer theory to form the canonical isomorphism between $H^1(F,\mu_{2,F})$ and $F^\times/(F^\times)^2$.

I claim that there is a unique order 2 unramified character of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$ and that it corresponds, under this bijection, to the unique order $2$ unramifed character of $F^\times$, which matches your example for $n=1$. Indeed, let us observe that we have a commuting diagram

$$\begin{matrix}\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(\mathcal{O}_F) & \to & H^1(\mathcal{O}_F,\mu_{2,\mathcal{O}_F}) & \to & 1\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow & &\\ \mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F) & \to & H^1(F,\mu_{2,F}) & \to & 1\end{matrix}$$

where the vertical maps are injections, and the top row is exact. To justify this exactness it suffices to note that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_F,\mathrm{Spin}_{2n+1,\mathcal{O}_F})=0$ by Lang's theorem and the fact that $H^1$ of a reductive group scheme is insensitive to passing to the closed point of a Henselian local ring.

After identifying $H^1(\mathcal{O}_F,\mu_{2,\mathcal{O}_F})=\mathcal{O}_F^\times/(\mathcal{O}_F^\times)^2$ we deduce from this that under the bijection of the proposition, $\chi\colon \mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)\to \mathbf{C}^\times$ is unramified if and only if $\nu\colon F^\times/(F^\times)^2\to \mathbf{C}^\times$ kills $\mathcal{O}_F^\times$ as desired.

To identify this character more explicitly, or to identify the characters of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$ in general, all you need from the above analysis is a character $\chi\colon G(F)\to \mathbf{C}^\times$ such that
$$\ker\chi=\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{Spin}_{2n+1}(F)\to \mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)).$$
For $n=1$ you apparently found this by taking the character

$$\omega\circ \det\colon \mathrm{PGL}_2(F)\to \mathbf{C}^\times$$

where $\omega$ is the unique order $2$ unramified character of $F^\times$, and transferring it to $\mathrm{SO}_3(F)$. Note that this character is well-defined as $\omega(\det(\alpha I_2))=1$. This works because $\mathrm{SL}_{2,F}=(\mathrm{PGL}_{2,F})^\mathrm{sc}$ and $\ker(\omega\circ \det)=\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{SL}_2(F)\to\mathrm{PGL}_2(F))$.

**EDIT:** Despite the above being purely abstract, it turns out that the map $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)\to F^\times/(F^\times)^2$ has a name, and a more explicit description! It's the so-called 'spinor norm'. See Section 5.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.03286v1.pdf), and [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Spinor_norm). So, if we denote this spinor norm by $\varsigma$, the above discussion shows that the characters of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$ are precisely those of the form $\chi\circ\varsigma$ where $\chi$ is an order $2$ character of $F^\times$, and that this unramified precisely when $\chi$ is.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer @AlexYoucis. Reading it again now, I am confused about your edit. You say that that any unramified character of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$ is given by composing the spinor norm with an order two unramified character of $F^\times$. Doesn't this imply that there are only two unramified characters of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(F)$? The unramified characters are supposed to form a complex torus, so I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @VerySlowlyLearning I don't think that is correct. Where have you seen that stated? There should be very few characters. Are you confusing unramified characters with unramified parameters?

Comment: for example this is V.2.4 in Renard-Schwartz's book, or just after remark 3.1 in Bernstein's notes, or 1.4.1 of Roche's chapter of the Ottawa lectures.

Comment: @VerySlowlyLearning Sorry, you are right. I didn't realize that you were using 'unramified character' in the sense of Bernstein decomposition -- I instead thought you meant characters that annihilated $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}(\mathcal{O}_F)$ (although I think this is non-standard terminology, especially because the existence of other maximal parahorics).

Comment: The reason I thought you *didn't* mean the Bernstein decomposition notion is that for semi-simple groups there are no unramified characters, right? Like (in Roche's terminology) if $\mathbb{G}$ is semi-simple, then $X_F(\mathbb{G})$ is trivial, so $G^\circ$ trivially equals $G$ and so $X_\mathrm{nr}(G)$ is the trivial torus $\{1\}$.  In particular, your claim of these unramified characters corresponding to the dual grouop doesn't hold true for this notion of unramified character, right? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thank you, that really clears up several misconceptions I had. I was kind of hoping I could ignore the fact that maximal compact subgroups are not all conjugate, the way they are for Lie groups, but of course I can't and this is one reason why. This solves quite a few confusions  I had. Thank you again!